# Displaying a function calculation

Tags: java, loops

I'm encountering an issue on a program I'm compiling. i got to display the actual calculation on function 2.The main program is called display11 and I'm calling the functions on the other class. can't figure it out whats wrong that is not displaying the loop. thanks a lot

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author ec1302696
 */
public class Functions 
{
    private int n;

    public void string_function(String name)
    {

        int optionChosen;
        String fname;
        String sname;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

       Functions fun = new Functions();



         System.out.println("Please enter full name");
         fname = sc.nextLine();   //accept first name entered by user
                            //****enter as a comment for now     fun.first(fname);

        fun.createname(fname);// this create name


        //display this is option 1,administrator name admin
        //ask for full name for generating username
        //call createname passing the username





    }

    public void number_function(String admin)
    {
        {
          int n, c, fact = 1;

      System.out.println("Enter a number to calculate it's factorial");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      n = in.nextInt();

      if ( n < 0 )
         System.out.println("Number should be non-negative.");
      else
      {
         for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
            fact = fact*c;

         System.out.println("Factorial of "+n+" is = "+fact);
        }

       // return fact;
       //this is option 2 ,administrator name admin 
        //read the factorial 
        //calcualte the fatorial
        // print it
    }
    }

    public void createname(String username)
    {
          String fname = fname.substring(0,1);

          System.out.println("The usernameis  " + fname);

    //string calcualte the string function to find the first letter ,and second name.
        //concatenate and print it.

    }           
    }
```

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author ec1302696
 */
public class Display11 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Functions fun = new Functions();// this create teh functions

        int optionChosen;

        String admin;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        admin = keyboard.nextLine();

        {
            System.out.println("Welcome please select option from menu below");
        }
        System.out.println("OPTION 1 – USERNAME");
        System.out.println("OPTION 2 - CALCULATE THE FACTORIAL");
        System.out.println("OPTION 3 - EXIT");
        optionChosen = keyboard.nextInt();


        if (optionChosen == 1) 
        {
            fun.string_function(admin);
        } 

        else if (optionChosen == 2) {

            {
                fun.number_function(admin);
            }

        }

        else if (optionChosen == 3)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change "String fname = fname.substring(0,1);" to "String fname = username.substring(0,1);", but other than that - what are you expecting to happen that doesn't happen? I ran your code and it seemed to work (after the change I mentioned).

Comment: Thanks. The only problem i encountered was the factorial number. The answer is correct but i got to display the calculation as well.will run it when i get home and see if it works ok.

Comment: Okay, see below my suggestion as to how to print the calculation along with the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the calculation of the factorial, change the calculation loop to something like this:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("Factorial of ").append(n).append(" is ");
for ( c = n ; c >0 ; c-- )
{
 result.append(c);
 if(c>1)
 {
  result.append(" * ");
 }
 fact = fact*c;
}

result.append(" = ").append(fact);
System.out.println(result);
```